# Why did returning in my jQuery loop not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had the following function, in which an ID would get looked up in an array of objects, looking for the matching object, and returning its name.

```
function find_object(id) {
    $.each(array_of_objects, function(index, obj) {
        if (obj.id === id) {
            console.log('returning');
            console.log(obj.name);
            return obj.name;
        }
    });
}
```

Very confusingly, it would always log the correct `obj.name`, but the returned value would always be `undefined`.

Eventually I realized that the `return` statement seemed to not actually return, and I rewrote the function like this:

```
function find_object(id) {
    var obj_name;
    $.each(array_of_objects, function(index, obj) {
        if (source.uuid === uuid) {
            obj_name = obj.name;
        }
    });
    return obj_name;
}
```

And this now works correctly. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` in your first example only `return`s from the iterator function you pass to `forEach`.

> but the returned value would always be undefined.

That is because your `find_object` function does not ever return anything specific. The standard return value for functions with no explicit return is `undefined` in Javascript.

Also, why are you not using `Array.prototype.find()`? Usage would be as easy as

```
function find_object(id) {
    return array_of_objects.find(obj => obj.id === id);
}
```

or, if you only want `name` from that:

```
function find_object(id) {
    return { name } = array_of_objects.find(obj => obj.id === id);
}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. And yes, I will also use `Array.prototype.find`